# "return deferred.promise(this)" is returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

The following code works if I resolve the deferred after 3 seconds using a timeout as follows...

```
    var myConstructor = function(){
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        this.message = "yo";
        setTimeout(function(){
            deferred.resolve();
            }, 3000);
        return deferred.promise(this);
    }
    var myObj = new myConstructor().done(function(){
        console.log(myObj.message);
    })
```

BUT if I resolve the deferred immediately without a timeout as follows...

```
    var myConstructor = function(){
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        this.message = "yo";
        deferred.resolve();
        return deferred.promise(this);
    }
    var myObj = new myConstructor().done(function(){
        console.log(myObj.message);
    })
```

... I then get the following errror: "Cannot read property 'message' of undefined" on the console.log line. Why does resolving the deferred immediately cause myObj to be undefined?

EDIT:

After I reviewed @T.J. Crowder's amazing answer, it became clear that this is the change I needed to make to make to the code:

```
    var myConstructor = function(){
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        this.message = "yo";
        deferred.resolve();
        return deferred.promise(this);
    }
    var myObj = new myConstructor();

    myObj.done(function(){
        console.log(myObj.message);
    })
```

Comment: because the done callback is being called immediately, so the `myObj` variable isn't created before the function is called

Comment: Besides, the design isn't great. I'd rather suggest to have a "static" function on the constructor which returns a promise and resolves it with a new instance of the "class"

Comment: @FelixKling I'm having a bit of trouble understanding what you mean. Do you think you could may be type out some code please?

Comment: Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/17fp2wc5/

Comment: @FelixKling: That's not a difference between whether it's static or not, it's a difference between whether you use the resolved value or not. Here's the same thing using the OP's constructor: http://jsfiddle.net/17fp2wc5/1/ (Not saying using the resolved value isn't a good idea, just that static-vs-instance is a non-issue.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I'm just referring to the design of the implementation, not the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> BUT if I resolve the deferred immediately without a timeout as follows...

When you call `done` on a `Deferred` that is **already** resolved, it *synchronously* calls its callback. In your case, that means that the callback is called *before* the assignment operation completes, and so `myObj` has no value (yet).

Let's break this code:

```
var myObj = new myConstructor().done(function(){
    console.log(myObj.message);
});
```

...into what happens when (where you're not using `setTimeout`):

1. Upon entry to the scope (before that line of code is executed in the step-by-step order of things), a variable called `myObj` is created with the value `undefined`.
2. `new myConstructor()` is evaluated, which:

   - Creates a new blank object backed by `myConstructor.prototype`
   - Calls `myConstructor` with `this` referring to that object
3. The anonymous function is created (but not executed).
4. `done` is called, passing in the anonymous function.

   - Because the `Deferred` is *already* resolved, `done` calls the callback immediately rather than waiting. *(I happen to be in the group of people who disagree with this design choice*, but that's the design jQuery's promises/deferreds have.)*
   - The callback accesses `myObj`, which has the value `undefined`, and so throws the exception
5. `done` returns and `myObj` gets its return value.

But when you use the `setTimeout`:

1. Upon entry to the scope (before that line of code is executed in the step-by-step order of things), a variable called `myObj` is created with the value `undefined`.
2. `new myConstructor()` is evaluated, which:

   - Creates a new blank object backed by `myConstructor.prototype`
   - Calls `myConstructor` with `this` referring to that object
   - Creates the timer callback but doesn't (yet) execute it
3. The anonymous function is created (but not executed).
4. `done` is called, passing in the anonymous function. Since the `Deferred` isn't (yet) resolved, it doesn't call the callback.
5. `done` returns and `myObj` gets its return value.
6. Some time later, the timer fires, and resolves the `Deferred`:

   - The callback is called.
   - The callback accesses `myObj`, which has the value from Step 5 and uses it successfully.

---

* "Design choice" - Having `done` call the callback *synchronously* if the `Deferred` is already resolved is a design choice. It trades off semantics with performance. Basically, the jQuery developers had two choices:

1. Call the callback synchronously, meaning that the semantics are chaotic (sometimes it's called synchronously, other times asynchronously), or
2. Call the callback asynchronously even when the state is already known (via `setTimeout(..., 0)` or similar), meaning that semantics are preserved (the callback is **always** asynchronous), but performance may suffer (browsers sometimes impose a minimum delay of 4ms on `setTimeout` callbacks, though not as consistently as the HTML5 spec would have them do it).

Which is right? That's totally a matter of opinion. Subjectively, for **me**, semantics should win: A callback that *may* be asynchronous should *always* be asynchronous — and if they'd made that choice, your code wouldn't have had the problem it had, because the callback would always happen *after* the assignment to `myObj` finished. But the jQuery developers, who are a smart bunch, made the other choice, which is their right. :-)

Comment: Regarding the "design choice" addition, I believe the Promise/A+ spec and ES6 follow exactly that rule: The callback always has to be executed in an asynchronous manner, independent of the state of the promise.

Comment: @t-j-crowder "The callback accesses myObj, which has the value undefined, and so throws the exception" . `undefined` , returned as no  arguments passed to `resolve()` or `resolveWith()` ? i.e.g, try `deferred.resolve(this.message);` , see post. Thanks

Comment: @FelixKling: Yes. jQuery's promises vary from Promises/A+ in more than one way. :-)

Comment: @guest271314: No, `myObj` is undefined because it hasn't had any other value assigned to it yet (see the first step-by-step above).

Comment: Interesting , `this.message` appear defined within `myConstructor` (`myObj`), and accessible within `.done()` callback - when included as argument to `.resolve()` ? Thanks

Comment: @guest271314: *"`this`...within `myConstructor`"* and *"`this`...within `.done` callback"* are two very different things. :-) I'm not quite sure I understand your comment; I don't see anything in documentation on [`Deferred#done`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) saying that `this` in the callback will be, although experimentally it looks like a `Deferred` object; but that object doesn't have a `message` property: http://jsbin.com/gadom/1 But the `done` callbacks *do* receive any arguments you give `resolve` as arguments.

Comment: @guest271314: Right. There, you're passing an argument to `resolve`, and using the argument (not `this`) in `done`.

Comment: @guest271314: Sorry, is there a question? I'm not at all clear what we're talking about. I understand how jQuery's promises work, I'm just not following what you're asking about. *(And apologies, but it's bedtime over here. :-) )*

Comment: Reason commented was due to this specific description: _"The callback accesses myObj, which has the value undefined, and so throws the exception"_ . Where , at piece below , was able to access `myObj` as `var myObj = new myConstructor()` , within `.done()` callback . Sought clarification as to that specific portion of description. Thanks for the illumination !

Answer (score 1):

Try utilizing [deferred.resolveWith()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.resolveWith/)

```js
var myConstructor = function(){
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        this.message = "yo";
        deferred.resolveWith(this, [this.messgae]);
        return deferred.promise();
    }
    var myObj = new myConstructor().done(function(){
        console.log(this.message); // `yo`
        $("body").append(this.message);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[1](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.resolveWith/): http://api.jquery.com/deferred.resolveWith/

Edit

Could also `resolve(this.message)`

```js
    var myConstructor = function(){
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        this.message = "yo";
        deferred.resolve(this.message);
        return deferred.promise();
    }
    var myObj = new myConstructor();

    myObj.done(function(msg){
        console.log(msg); // `yo`
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```